# RTCMultiConnection not able to switch off the video and audio on local..?

Tags: rtcmulticonnection

Not Able to switch off video on my local system, although I am able to do it with the socket signalling server, but that is not saving the bandwidth, I want to save the bandwidth, by turning the audio and video off in reality, and same should happen at peer side.

Comment: Please check discussion on this page: http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/mute/#disqus_thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To switch of Video and Audio at your local system and to see that same effect on the peers side, you need to change the stream and renegotiate with the peer using new SDP constraints, and session constraints.

Comment: this seems fine, will try to implement according to this answer.